# Commerce Products Display Page Using Views

Tags: commerce, views

The usual way to display Commerce products is

**1. Create Products using Commerce Module Interface**

**2. Create a Content  Type for Products Line Items by referencing the products**

But I have too many different products... should I have to create contents after adding each commerce Products??

**I used two views for each products one to create a products listing and other for product display page using contextual filters and by passing the Product ID**

Product Listing Page path : /products-list

Product Display Page      : /products/product1

By passing the product ID via URL.

Is this a write way to do it... Or is there anything efficient and meaningful than this method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module "https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auto_product_display". then you can use Views to show the product display nodes.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.. This module works pretty cool.. :) But should I have to create a node page for each product.. That keeps disturbing me :(

Comment: yes, you can read some more about that here : https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-displays. Also here is a very good video explains it as well: https://drupalize.me/videos/adding-product-displays?p=1154